# Is there any faster way to access const hash map, if the key is guarantee to be found?

Tags: c++

I think in `std::unordered_map`, no matter `[]`(not working for const map, I know that) or `at()` or `find()`, they are have some moves to handle the case if the key is not found, So I got some questions:
For non-const map:

1. Does the "key not found" moves influences the efficiency? (Hardly I can imagine if not).
2. If yes, any way I can access element faster if I guarantee that the key I passed in will always be found?
3. How about a const map?

Comment: This is tangential, but if you're that worried about lookup performance, `std::map` is quite possibly an inferior choice of data structure. Every node is a pointer hop (vs. a vector) and lookup is logarithmic (vs. a hash map).

Comment: I think changes `map` to `unordered_map` makes no difference in this question. Myself use map because hash map takes more memory than a tree map, and memory is expensive in my case, but any way, I'll change to `unoredered_map` to make no distraction.

Comment: "hash map takes more memory than a tree map". This is rather odd. What number of keys do you normally have? If `std::unordered_map` is unsuitable for your task, then you need to find a different implementation of hashtable, not use `std:::map` (which is basically bad in every respect).

Comment: Just speculating: if your use-case is a const map and you're looking up known, existing values, you should have a look at [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) - basically performing very cheap hashes guaranteed collision free only for the specific set of values. If memory is a concern then the *minimal perfect hash* function is what you want, otherwise it's going to be a trade-off between memory and hash function performance.